# How to categorise data in python nested list

Tags: python, list

I need to categorize python nested list as follow.

```
[
['amal', 20],
['kamal', 25],
['amal', 30]
]
```

the answer should be,

```
[amal,20,30]
[kamal,25]
```

Comment: Interesting! But where is your code?

Comment: Who are you talking to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the sublists according to the first value:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter as g

[[k, *(i[1] for i in v)] for k,v in groupby(sorted(l, key=g(0)), g(0))]
# [['amal', 20, 30], ['kamal', 25]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would work with a groupby on a Pandas DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['amal', 20],
    ['kamal', 25],
    ['amal', 30]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['key', 'value'])
grouped = data.groupby('key').agg(list)
print(grouped.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way one way of doing that.

```
list1 = [
['amal', 20],
['kamal', 25],
['amal', 30]
]

ls2=[]
k = set([i[0] for i in list1])
for i in k: 
    k2 = [ j[1] for j in list1 if j[0]==i]
    k2.insert(0,i)
    ls2.append(k2)

ls2
# Output: [['kamal', 25], ['amal', 20, 30]]
```